Swag and Authelia: Skip Authelia if certain header is passed
I want to have a condition on the import of Authelia for some sub domain.
I have a fairly basic nginx conf file like this
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name some-app.*;

    include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;

    client_max_body_size 0;

    # enable for ldap auth (requires ldap-location.conf in the location block)
    #include /config/nginx/ldap-server.conf;

    # enable for Authelia (requires authelia-location.conf in the location block)
    include /config/nginx/authelia-server.conf;

    # enable for Authentik (requires authentik-location.conf in the location block)
    #include /config/nginx/authentik-server.conf;
    
    location / {
        # enable the next two lines for http auth
        #auth_basic "Restricted";
        #auth_basic_user_file /config/nginx/.htpasswd;

        # enable for ldap auth (requires ldap-server.conf in the server block)
        #include /config/nginx/ldap-location.conf;

        # enable for Authelia (requires authelia-server.conf in the server block)
        include /config/nginx/authelia-location.conf;

        # enable for Authentik (requires authentik-server.conf in the server block)
        #include /config/nginx/authentik-location.conf;

        include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
        include /config/nginx/resolver.conf;
        set $upstream_app some-container;
        set $upstream_port 3000;
        set $upstream_proto http;
        proxy_pass $upstream_proto://$upstream_app:$upstream_port;

    }

    location ~ (/some-app)?/api {
        # enable for Authelia (requires authelia-server.conf in the server block)
        include /config/nginx/authelia-location.conf;

        include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
        include /config/nginx/resolver.conf;
        set $upstream_app some-container;
        set $upstream_port 3000;
        set $upstream_proto http;
        proxy_pass $upstream_proto://$upstream_app:$upstream_port;
    }
}

I have tried to wrap the import of Authelia in a block like this:
if ($http_skip_authelia != "some-really-long-value-here") {}
And therefore if I receive the header Skip-Authelia with a certain value, Authelia would be skipped.
Except that this doesn't work. I think it's because this is loaded once and not done per request.
I'm not too sure how to achieve this.
Also if you wonder the use case, I've got a web app (which I can use Authelia with) and a native android app (that wouldn't support Authelia on the API) I want to use.
For the web, I want Authelia everywhere. For the app, I can set a custom header to be passed for each request in order to not apply Authelia check.
If this cannot be done nginx side, maybe somewhere on Authelia side?
Thanks!

Have you tried performing the conditionally applying the directives in the /config/nginx/authelia-location.conf file?

Yes I did encounter some error though, I do not have the code I tried right now but it was an if on the header. I could post it tomorrow but if you have an example in mind please share
